# undefined en petición a servidor AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, sql, ajax

he estado intentado mostrar una imagen en una modal, esa imagen se muestra en función de un elemento seleccionado, por eso uso la peticón ajax, que me muestre la imagen de acuerdo al elemento seleccionado, pero cuando hago la petición me muestra un mensaje de undefined acá dejo la función AJAX, la sentencia SQL y el controlador:

El undefined lo marca en la línea de:

```
alert(respuesta.img);



function mostrarImagen(art){
  var url="<?php echo URL?>";
  cod_ar=art;
  alert(cod_ar);

  $.ajax({
    method:"POST",
    url: url + "Home/mostrarImagen",
    datatype:'json',
    data:{articulo : cod_ar}
  })
  .done(function(respuesta){
    alert(respuesta.img);
  })
  .fail(function(error){
    alert(error);
  })
}



//MODELO
public function mostrarImagen(){
        $sql="SELECT nombre_imagen as img FROM imagen as i INNER JOIN articulo as a ON i.idimagen=a.imagen_idimagen WHERE idarticulo=?";
        $stm = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $stm->bindParam(1, $this->id_articulo);
        $stm->execute();
        return $stm->fetch();
    }



//CONTROLADOR
    public function mostrarImagen(){
        $mdo=new mdo();
        $mdo->__SET("id_articulo",$_POST["articulo"]);
        $rtado=$mdo->mostrarImagen()->img;
        echo json_decode($rtado);
        var_dump($rtado);
    }
```

EL RESULTADO QUE LANZA LA RESPUESTA DEL CONTROLADOR ES:

```
object(stdClass)#7 (1) { ["img"]=> string(14) "NEW_PITNEY.png" }
```

CLARO ESTÁ QUE LA RESPUESTA ES DE ACORDE AL ELEMENTO SELECCIONADO

Comment: El error es que en `JS`, la variable `respuesta` es la `img`. Si prestas atención en el controlador de `PHP` tienes que `$rtado=$mdo->mostrarImagen()->img;`. **PD**:  imagino que `var_dump($rtado);` esta solo por debuging

Comment: Si, así, pero cuando llamo a respuesta con el elemento img, sigue siendo undefined

Comment: En tu controlador solo tienes que cambiar `$rtado=$mdo->mostrarImagen()->img;`, por esto `$rtado=$mdo->mostrarImagen();` y sacar el `var_dump`.

Comment: Dicho sea de paso, si estas usando `fetch` con `PDO` (_así parece_), ten en cuenta que el `fetch_style` por defecto devuelve un arreglo y no un objeto.

Comment: Acabé de quitar el var_dump, a su vez modifiqué donde estaba llamando al método $rtado=$mdo->mostrarImagen(); lo dejé como decías, pero sigue indefinida, he intentado mostrarla cambiando el tipo de fetch a fetchAll, pero no es viable ya que el resultado que se devuelve en la consulta es solo un registro y no muchos

Comment: ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta y agregar el resultado del `var_dump($rtado);`?

Comment: Ya la edité amigo

Comment: Tienes que quitar esto: `var_dump($rtado);`, de lo contrario te estará fastidiando la salida, que no debe ser otra cosa que un JSON.

Comment: Lo hice, pero no funciona, he modificado la respuesta en el ajax para comvertir la  respuesta a un JSON, pero ni así

Comment: Ya funciona, lo que hice fue convertir lo que recibía y ahora se mestra correctamente